# ¿Como cargar imagenes en orden al azar?

Tags: javascript

Me pidieron agregar una imagenes en una webapp. El codigo que ven sirve para hacer que unas imagenes hagan un efecto "Random", para que siempre esten en una posicion distinta.

El problema es que cuando agrego otras imagenes que quiero que tengan también ese efecto, les coloco ese mismo codigo (copiando el código y cambiándole el id y la clase), pero las imagenes quedan encimadas y las originales ya no hacen el efecto. ¿Alguna sugerencia?.

P.D. No soy egresado y no estudio Ingenieria. Me estoy capacitando para este trabajo.

```
var ships = []
var time_anim = 400

$(document).ready(function () {
    ships = $("#baraja  .movimiento");
    shuffle(9);
});

function shuffle(level) {
    var c = randInt(2, 3)
    cycle(getElements(ships, c))

    if (level > 1) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            shuffle(level - 1)
        }, time_anim)
    }
}

function randInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

function cycle(items) {
    var pos0 = $(items[0]).position()

    for (i = 1; i < items.length; i++) {
        var sh = items[i];
        var shp = $(sh).position();

        $(items[i - 1]).animate({
            "left": shp.left,
            "top": shp.top
        }, time_anim);
    }

    $(sh).animate({
        "left": pos0.left,
        "top": pos0.top
    }, time_anim);
}

function getElements(arr, n) {
    var used = []
    var result = []

    while (result.length < n && result.length < arr.length) {
        var i = randInt(0, arr.length - 1)
        if (jQuery.inArray(i, used) !== -1) {
            continue;
        }

        used.push(i)
        result.push(arr[i])
    }

    return result;
}
```

Este es el link de la pagina y la imagenes: [link](https://www.informoyvoto.org/News/Candidates). Yo quiero agregar una nueva seccion con imagenes debajo de esas que ya estan, que tengan el efecto de baraja.

Comment: podrias agregar tambien tu html ya que necesitamos reproducir tu error para poder ayudarte!

Comment: Si cambias shuffle(9) por shuffle(ships.length) ?

Comment: Cuando termina de hacer la baraja, quedan encimadas.

Comment: este es el link de la seccion: https://www.informoyvoto.org/News/Candidates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:
tu error se da porque solo seleccion los elementos con la clase `effect` pero hay varios elementos llamados `effect2`.

**ejemplo:**

```
var ships = []
var time_anim = 400

$(document).ready(function () {
    // debes seleccionar todos los elementos que contengan la palabra effect
    ships = $('#MainDiv div[class*="effect"]');
    shuffle(9)
});

function shuffle(level) {
    var c = randInt(2,3)
    cycle(getElements(ships, c))

    if (level > 1) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            shuffle(level - 1)
        }, time_anim)
    }
}

function randInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

function cycle(items) {
    var pos0 = $(items[0]).position()

    for (i = 1; i < items.length; i++) {
        var sh = items[i];
        var shp = $(sh).position();

        $(items[i - 1]).animate({
            "left": shp.left,
            "top": shp.top
        }, time_anim);
    }

    $(sh).animate({
        "left": pos0.left,
        "top": pos0.top
    }, time_anim);
}

function getElements(arr, n) {
    var used = []
    var result = []

    while (result.length < n && result.length < arr.length) {
        var i = randInt(0, arr.length - 1)
        if (jQuery.inArray(i, used) !== -1) {
            continue;
        }

        used.push(i)
        result.push(arr[i])
    }

    return result;
}
```